# what is the meaning of "free egress"?

Tags: american-english

the following text has been extracted of Harper Lee's new novel. I was wondering the "free egress" means commute without pay toll or it means commute without trouble?

Bus service was erratic and seemed to go nowhere, but the Federal Government had forced a highway or two through the swamps, thus giving the citizens an opportunity for **free egress**. But few people took advantage of the roads, and why should they? If you did not want much, there was plenty.

Thank you,

Comment: Did you consult a dictionary??

Answer (score 1):

An "egress" is a act of leaving. The author means that that the highways gave people an opportunity to leave freely. That is, the roads meant people were not trapped.

Comment: Here "egress" is a noun, meaning exit.

Comment: @deadrat, while it is a noun in this case, yes, it refers here to the act of exiting, not a physical exit.

Comment: When you go to exit (to leave), you take your exit (act of leaving) or you may take the exit (way of leaving).  In both cases, the object of "take" is a noun, not a verb, and a noun is required for the object of the preposition "for."  But perhaps we're in violent agreement here.

Comment: @deadrat In any case, I edited my answer to be more careful about parts of speech.